# Search a list of unic values in another list. Linux

Tags: grep

Im trying filter only specific values in a very long list with repeated values.

The long list:

```
ASUR B 356.660 
FEMSA UBD 181.670 
AMX L 15.060 
ASUR B 356.290 
ASUR B 356.480 
WALMEX * 56.510 
IENOVA * 86.030 
IENOVA * 86.010 
...
```

The specific values to filter the other list:

```
AMX L
IENOVA *
XLRE *
XLU *
...
```

I was trying to use:

```
grep -f EmisorasSIC.txt EmisorasInfo.txt
```

But it gave me a result that i don't want, for example:
By searching AMXL gave me  WALMEX (W**A**L**M**E**X**)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NfHT.png)

Is there a way to search values in a list line by line?
Or to search certain values from one list in another list?

Thanks

Comment: You can add `-F` (or `--fixed-strings`) with to specify literal string matching instead of regular expression matching - however, even as a regular expression, `AMXL` should not have matched `WALMEX`

Comment: ... unless your list actually contains bracketed entries like `[AMX L]`